# Why should we avoid the future API when using gRPC with Python?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

In the [official documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/#python), it is suggested that:

> Using the future API in the sync stack results in the creation of an extra thread. Avoid the future API if possible.

**Why is that?**

Another question is, in the source code of [grpc python](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5222eafdc1aad755cf4cbadd6396d26c6609261a/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_server.py#L1128), they also use the future API, so am I confusing these two `future`s?

> def create_server(thread_pool: futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, ...)